# Laravel 301 редирект (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, nginx, redirect

После переноса старого проекта с Joomla на Laravel возникла необходимость сделать 301 редирект с некоторых ссылкок которые остались в индексе.

Например:
Было (осталось в индексе) - http://example.com/ru/restoran
Стало - http://example.com/ru/restorants

Необходимо сделать 301 редирект через `.htaccess` который лежит в папке public

Содержимое файла стандартное:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Пытаюсь сделать так: `Redirect 301 ^/ru/restoran ^/ru/restorants`
или так : `RewriteRule ^ru/restoran ^ru/restorants [R=301,NC,L]`
Не отрабатывает. Такое ощущение что сам файл не отрабатывает. Веб сервер nginx. Подскажите как правильно сделать 301 редирект через `.htaccess` в Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в конфиге nginx:

```
location = /ru/restoran {
    return 301 http://example.com/ru/restorants
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно сделать 301 редирект через .htaccess в Laravel при использовании веб-сервера nginx невозможно в принципе, так как nginx не поддерживает работу с .htaccess

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/